# Missing data warning R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataframe with climatic values like temperature_max, temperature_min... in diferent locations. The data collection is a time series data there are some especific days in which there are no data registration. I woul like to impute taking in account date and also the location (place variable in the dataframe)

I have tried to impute those missing values with `amelia`. But no imputation is done with warning information

Checking variables:

```
head(df): PLACE, DATE, TEMP_MAX, TEMP_MIN, TEMP_AVG

PLACE    DATE        TEMP_MAX      TEMP_MIN     TEMP_AVG
F      12/01/2007       19.7         2.5          10.1
F      13/01/2007       18.8         3.5          10.4
F      14/01/2007       17.3         2.4          10.4
F      15/01/2007       19.5         4.0          9.2
F      16/01/2007       
F      17/01/2007       21.5         2.8          9.7
F      18/01/2007       17.7         3.3          12.9
F      19/01/2007       18.3         3.8          9.7
A      16/01/2007       17.7         3.4          9.7
A      17/01/2007       
A      18/01/2007       19.7         6.2          10.4
A      19/01/2007       17.7         3.8          10.1
A      20/01/2007       18.6        3.8          12.9
```

This is just some of the records of my data set.

```
DF = amelia(df, m=4, ts= c("DATE"), cs = c("PLACE"))
```

where DATE is time series data (01/01/2001, 02/01/2001, 03/01/2001...) but if you filter by PLACE the time series is not equal (not the same star and end time).

I have 3 questions:

1. I am not sure if I should have the time series data complete for all the places, I mean same start and end time for all the places.
2. I am not using lags or polytime parameters so, am I imputting correctly taking in account time series influence? I am not sure about how to use lag parameter although I have checked the R package information.
3. The last question is that when I try to use that code there is a warning 
   and no imputation is done.

> Warning: There are observations in the data that are completely missing. 
>            These observations will remain unimputed in the final datasets.
>
> -- Imputation 1 --
>
> No missing data in bootstrapped sample:  EM chain unnecessary
>
> -- Imputation 2 --
>
> No missing data in bootstrapped sample:  EM chain unnecessary
>
> -- Imputation 3 --
>
> No missing data in bootstrapped sample:  EM chain unnecessary
>
> -- Imputation 4 --
>
> No missing data in bootstrapped sample:  EM chain unnecessary

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: Please add some of your data as this is not reproducible. Also make sure to specify all packages you are using and the lines of code that lead to the errors. Without knowing what you did exactly it is hard to help.

Comment: Amelia was working fine until last week. Now I get your same message error by using the same code that was working last week. Don't know what is happening though.

Comment: I contacted the author of the package. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the software it does not matter if you have different start and end dates for different places. I think that it is more up to you and your thoughts on the data. I would ask myself, if those were missing data (missing at random) thus I would create empty rows in your data set or not.
2. You want to use lags in order to use past values of the variable to improve the prediction of missing values. It is not mandatory (i.e., the function can impute missing data even without such a specification) but it can be useful.
3. I contacted the author of the package and he told me that you need to specify the splinetime or polytime arguments to make sure that Amelia will use the time-series information to impute. For instance, if you set polytime = 3, it will impute based on a cubic of time. If you do that, I think you shouldn't see that error anymore.